# Three.js - changing collada texture works, but not with canvas

Tags: canvas, three.js, textures, collada, uv-mapping

I am digging into Three.js and am experimenting with vrml, and now with collada files.

Importing a collada file works. It works with webGL AND canvas as a fallback : my 3D model rotates, shows the model… and in webGL i can even have that wonderful effects like shadows, bumps, etc.

I did achieve loading another texture file, assigning it to the webGL renderer… but in this particular case, the canvas renderer completely fails : frames drop from 60fps to 2fps, and the texture "slides" on the polygons.

I guess i miss something in order to "fix" the texture to the model, or when importing the texture maybe do i miss some parameters ? Once again it is working fine without changing the texture… but i really need to do so :p

Here is a working preview :
http://dokmixer.com/three-tests/

And here is the part where the magic fails :

```
//model loading
      loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
      loader.load('models/collada/7cm.005.dae',function colladaReady( collada ){
        player = collada.scene;
        skin = collada.skins [ 0 ];
        player.scale.x = player.scale.y = player.scale.z = 0.10;

        if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Safari') != -1 && navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') == -1) {
          var newskinTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/collada/dokMixer.png' );
          themodel = collada.scene.children[0];
          themodel.material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: newskinTexture, overdraw: true} );
        }
        else {
          var newskinTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/collada/dokMixer.png' );
          var bumpTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'models/collada/noise.png' );
          bumpTexture.anisotropy = 2;
          player_material = collada.scene.children[0].material;
          themodel = collada.scene.children[0];
          themodel.material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { map: newskinTexture, bumpMap: bumpTexture, bumpScale: 0.05} );
        }

        //utile pour avoir les ombres
        daemesh = player.children[0];
        daemesh.castShadow = true;
        daemesh.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add( player ); 
      });
```

The part to look into is the first if statement (as i am testing canvas with Safari, before expanding to other canvas enabled devices). When assigning a new material, the renderer completely fails. You can test the effect by going to the page with Safari.

Note : i am working on OSX if that can be of any relevant information.

Any help appreciated :)

EDIT : i guess i'm setting here a new material, instead of replacing only the source image file ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, finally found a workaround !

The way i swapped texture was wrong for canvas, i assume it is a bug.
I found a clue on this answer by [psychok7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15025319/changing-texture-and-color-on-three-js-collada-object?rq=1).

So well, instead of loading and THEN changing a texture… i changed the code in the ColladaLoader.js file. Well, almost the same. Since i use "load" i added a couple times imageReload in the load function, and when calling the "parse" function. Then, in the parse function i did some changes too as the code given was wrong on their link.
For those interested, a list of the changes, and my final code. Sadly i couldn't achieve the "same" functionnalities (sending an array of textures, doing the regExp thing, and replacing several textures at once), this part was buggy for me, and since i needed to change only one texture file…

- i don't do iamge.init_from = iR.new_image; in the regExp loop stuff… but instead add image.init_from = iR; just before the regExp thing.
- When calling the function in my file, i send an array… it was not documented, no examples, and had a hard time understanding it. Well, don't try to directly send the .png or .jpeg url, put that names in a table before and in the function call that array. Don't forget to remove the paths, as it should be the same path as described INSIDE your collada file (so in my case, just the texture name, as my collada file shares the same folder as the textures).
- in the code of psychok, there was obviously a mistake in the "parseLib" calls, where he writes stuff like parseLib( "//dae:library_materials/dae:material", Material, "material" ); instead of parseLib( "library_materials material", Material, "material" ); (which is working, and is the original code).

So, long story short, here's the code where i call the collada

```
 loader = new THREE.ColladaLoader();
      newtextures = ['dokMixer.png'];
      loader.load('models/collada/7cm.005.dae', newtextures,function colladaReady( collada ){
        player = collada.scene;
        skin = collada.skins [ 0 ];
        player.scale.x = player.scale.y = player.scale.z = 0.10;

        //i'll add code here later for extra bump mapping on webgl versions

        //usefull for shadows on webgl version
        daemesh = player.children[0];
        daemesh.castShadow = true;
        daemesh.receiveShadow = true;

        scene.add( player ); 
      });
```

And here's the code inside the colladaLoader. It is a replacement of the functions load, and parse.

```
function load ( url, imageReplace, readyCallback, progressCallback ) {

    var length = 0;

    if ( document.implementation && document.implementation.createDocument ) {

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

        request.onreadystatechange = function() {

            if( request.readyState == 4 ) {

                if( request.status == 0 || request.status == 200 ) {


                    if ( request.responseXML ) {

                        readyCallbackFunc = readyCallback;
                        parse( request.responseXML, imageReplace, undefined, url );

                    } else if ( request.responseText ) {

                        readyCallbackFunc = readyCallback;
                        var xmlParser = new DOMParser();
                        var responseXML = xmlParser.parseFromString( request.responseText, "application/xml" );
                        parse( responseXML, imageReplace, undefined, url );

                    } else {

                        console.error( "ColladaLoader: Empty or non-existing file (" + url + ")" );

                    }

                }

            } else if ( request.readyState == 3 ) {

                if ( progressCallback ) {

                    if ( length == 0 ) {

                        length = request.getResponseHeader( "Content-Length" );

                    }

                    progressCallback( { total: length, loaded: request.responseText.length } );

                }

            }

        }

        request.open( "GET", url, true );
        request.send( null );

    } else {

        alert( "Don't know how to parse XML!" );

    }

}

function parse( doc, imageReplace, callBack, url ) {

    COLLADA = doc;
    callBack = callBack || readyCallbackFunc;

    if ( url !== undefined ) {

        var parts = url.split( '/' );
        parts.pop();
        baseUrl = ( parts.length < 1 ? '.' : parts.join( '/' ) ) + '/';

    }

    parseAsset();
    setUpConversion();
    images = parseLib( "library_images image", _Image, "image" );

    for(var i in imageReplace) {
        var iR = imageReplace[i];

        for(var i in images) {
            var image = images[i];
            //added line, but no multiple textures !
            image.init_from = iR; 

            //RegExp and patt.test not working
            var patt=new RegExp('[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*\/'+iR.name,'g');
            //if(image.id==iR.id)
            //
            if(patt.test(image.init_from))
                image.init_from = iR.new_image; 
        }//for
    }


    materials = parseLib( "library_materials material", Material, "material" );
    effects = parseLib( "library_effects effect", Effect, "effect" );
    geometries = parseLib( "library_geometries geometry", Geometry, "geometry" );
    cameras = parseLib( "library_cameras camera", Camera, "camera" );
    lights = parseLib( "library_lights light", Light, "light" );
    controllers = parseLib( "library_controllers controller", Controller, "controller" );
    animations = parseLib( "library_animations animation", Animation, "animation" );
    visualScenes = parseLib( "library_visual_scenes visual_scene", VisualScene, "visual_scene" );
    // materials = parseLib( "//dae:library_materials/dae:material", Material, "material" );
    // effects = parseLib( "//dae:library_effects/dae:effect", Effect, "effect" );
    // geometries = parseLib( "//dae:library_geometries/dae:geometry", Geometry, "geometry" );
    // cameras = parseLib( ".//dae:library_cameras/dae:camera", Camera, "camera" );
    // controllers = parseLib( "//dae:library_controllers/dae:controller", Controller, "controller" );
    // animations = parseLib( "//dae:library_animations/dae:animation", Animation, "animation" );
    // visualScenes = parseLib( ".//dae:library_visual_scenes/dae:visual_scene", VisualScene, "visual_scene" );

    morphs = [];
    skins = [];

    daeScene = parseScene();
    scene = new THREE.Object3D();

    for ( var i = 0; i < daeScene.nodes.length; i ++ ) {

        scene.add( createSceneGraph( daeScene.nodes[ i ] ) );

    }

// unit conversion
scene.position.multiplyScalar(colladaUnit);
scene.scale.multiplyScalar(colladaUnit);

    createAnimations();

    var result = {

        scene: scene,
        morphs: morphs,
        skins: skins,
        animations: animData,
        dae: {
            images: images,
            materials: materials,
            cameras: cameras,
            effects: effects,
            geometries: geometries,
            controllers: controllers,
            animations: animations,
            visualScenes: visualScenes,
            scene: daeScene
        }

    };

    if ( callBack ) {

        callBack( result );

    }

    return result;

}
```

Hope this helps someone ! Have fun ! :)